# Does Python have a similar control mechanism to Java's CountDownLatch?

Tags: python, multithreading

So, I will start by saying that this is for a homework problem. My professor gave us an assignment which must be written once in Java and once in another language; I chose the second language to be Python since I'm at least a little familiar with it. The program must work in the following way:

```
start the main method/thread, which we will call parent
start thread child 1 from the parent
start thread grandchild from thread child 1
start thread child 2 from the parent
print grandchild from the grandchild thread
print child 2 from the child 2 thread
print child 1 from the child 1 thread
print parent from the main method/parent thread
```

These things must be done in this order. I have written code that does this in Java using CountDownLatch in order to organize the way these things occur. However, I didn't see a similar mechanism in Python (although I'm less familiar with Python than Java). Is there a similar mechanism that maybe I just can't find because I don't know what it's called?

Answer (score 27):

you can implement CountDownLatch using threading.Condition like this:

```
import threading

class CountDownLatch(object):
    def __init__(self, count=1):
        self.count = count
        self.lock = threading.Condition()

    def count_down(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.count -= 1
        if self.count <= 0:
            self.lock.notifyAll()
        self.lock.release()

    def await(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        while self.count > 0:
            self.lock.wait()
        self.lock.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `Semaphore` or `Condition` classes from the `threading` module.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.2 added a `Barrier` class that has some overlapping functionality with a `CountDownLatch`. The main differences are it can be reset, and there isn't a way to count down without waiting.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects